# Haystrack rebuild_index Elasticsearch SerializationError

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I am creating a knowledge base and in order to make the search system I decided to use Haystack with Elasticsearch. I am using :

- Python 3.5
- Django 1.8.8 because Haystack seems to be incompatible with Django
  1.9.x
- Elasticsearch 2.3.0
- Urllib3
- Haystack 2.4.1

I followed the installation steps from :
[django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#installation](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#installation)

At the end, when i am trying to make the command `python3.5 manage.py rebuild_index` i have the following error :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/elasticsearch/serializer.py", line 72, in loads
    deserializer = self.serializers[mimetype]
KeyError: 'text/html'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 346, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 394, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 445, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/haystack/management/commands/rebuild_index.py", line 25, in handle
    call_command('clear_index', **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 120, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 445, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/haystack/management/commands/clear_index.py", line 56, in handle
    backend.clear(commit=self.commit)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/haystack/backends/elasticsearch_backend.py", line 234, in clear
    self.conn.indices.delete(index=self.index_name, ignore=404)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 69, in _wrapped
    return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/indices.py", line 200, in delete
    params=params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 353, in perform_request
    data = self.deserializer.loads(data, headers.get('content-type'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/elasticsearch/serializer.py", line 74, in loads
    raise SerializationError('Unknown mimetype, unable to deserialize: %s' % mimetype)
elasticsearch.exceptions.SerializationError: Unknown mimetype, unable to deserialize: text/html
```

I don't understand ! Can somebody help me to configure my search system ?

Comment: In the documentation they are talking about version 1.x. Just to try it out I would install 1.7.x and see if the problem is resolved. Could be you need some other settings, 2.x has some changes in the cluster config and network bindings. So first try 1.7 or see if others got it working with 2.x. No Django user myself.

Comment: Thanks for advice but i still got the same error ...